# How can I avoid a str_split error in php?

Tags: php

I'm trying to split a variable at every character, but I ran across this error:

> Warning: str_split() expects parameter 2 to be long, string

The code is:

```
$split = str_split($num, "");
```

With `$num` being taken from the url, which only consist of numbers.
How can fix this?

Comment: The second parameter should be _split_length : Maximum length of the chunk._ More details here [str-split.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

Comment: You haven't quoted the exact error message, but it is clear. The second argument should be a number (if provided) not a string "". [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

Comment: Please view str_split() about http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php. The second parameter should be split_length OR Maximum length of the chunk OR for you 1.

Comment: *"How can I avoid a str_split error in php?"* -- it's as simple as reading the [documentation of `str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter should be a number like this

```
<?php
$num = 100;

$split = str_split($num, 1);
print_r($split);
```

RESULT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
)
```

In fact you can leave the second parameter out if it is a 1 like this

```
<?php
$num = 100;

$split = str_split($num);
print_r($split);
```

And you will get the same result

Comment: Default is 1 in `str_split`

Answer (score 1):

As you said ***split a variable at every character*** you can just run

```
$split = str_split($num);
```

Make sure `$num` in not empty

Syntax `str_split(string,length)`

---

**Example**

```
<?php
    print_r(str_split("1234"));
?>
```

Outputs - `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 )`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$splitText = 1223;
$split = str_split((string) $splitText); //only on php 7 
var_dump($split);
```

you will get this:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
```

Usage: `array str_split ( string $string [, int $split_length = 1 ] )`, but check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php).

Comment: Read it first **which only consist of numbers.** `$splitText ='I am a hero!';` ???